# Is there an app that generates chunks for Minecraft maps using a command line?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm looking for an application that takes a seed and some parameters (such as X,Z coords and radius etc) and builds the files that contain chuck data. I want this so that I can load a large area and then upload this to a map generator site like http://www.minecraftworldmap.com so that I can see a large area of the map before I play the game.

Comment: Voting to reopen as per http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-mod-rec-really-am-umbrella-category-that-we-want-to-use-or-is-it-confusing

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the program '[Amidst](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v2036-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-ect-finder/)'. It scans a world or builds from a seed to show what the world will look like: biomes, structures, etc.

You can see as much of the map as you want, as far as you want. It's not amazingly detailed, but every biome is shown.

Answer (score 0):

[Minecraft Land Generator](https://github.com/Morlok8k/MinecraftLandGenerator) does this, though it requires a server jar and although it says it was updated 6/1/12, the forum thread and the github page do not mention whether it is compatible with the current server versions.

Alternatively, you can use MCedit to pre-generate chunks. It's not as automatic as a command line tool, but its chunk control features can generate chunks within a selection.